# Nginx: Is there encryption-decryption module?

Tags: encryption, nginx

We are working on scaling our object store layer, while making sure we have all security primitives. The proposed design will have http access via Nginx; and if we could encrypt/decrypt at the Nginx layer, the system would scale much better. But couldn't find any modules for Nginx. Thoughts ?

Comment: Why would encrypting/decrypting at nginx make it scale better?

Comment: Our architecture has nginx front-ending the filers.So doing the encryption/decryption at this layer scales. Otherwise we would need to upload the file, encrypt it and then send the file to nginx; similarly we would need to download the file from nginx, decrypt it and send to client ...

Comment: Krishna, did you ever find a solution to this?